# I want to add tooltip to svg element. Have tried base CSS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, tooltip

I have a school project where I have to make a "treasure" map. My idea was to get a world map as a SVG elements with countries and continents. I got the map where every country has its border as  elements. I tried to create tooltip with vanilla CSS but with no results and have googled couple of javascript and jquery solutions for tooltips but got no results.
I was wondering if its even possible because I'm kinda losing hope already.

I tried using this piece of jquery for tooltip

js file:

```
(function() {
var infoElem = $('.info');
infoElem.each(function() {
    var self = $(this),
        selfTooltiptext = self.data('tooltip-text');
    if (selfTooltiptext) $('<span/>', {class: 'tooltip', text: selfTooltiptext}).appendTo(self);
});
```

})();

SVG path in html:

```
<a href="#" class="info" data-tooltip-text="Hint">
    <path d="M1113.7 124.6l0.9 1-2.6 3.4 2.4 5.6-1.6 1.9-3.8-0.1-4.4-2.2-2.1-0.7-3.8 1-0.1-3.5-1.5 0.8-3.3-2.1-1-3.4 5.5-1.7 5.6-0.8 5.1 0.9 4.7-0.1z" id="EE" name="Estonia">
    </path>
        </a>
```

CSS:

```
.tooltip {
display: block;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 120%;
width: 190px;
padding: 5px;
border-radius: 10px;
background-color: cadetblue;
color: #fff;
line-height: normal;
text-transform: none;
font-size: 12px;
opacity: 0;
transform: scaleY(0);
transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.tooltip:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    left: 10px;
    bottom: -5px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 5px solid burlywood;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
}

.info:hover .tooltip {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scaleY(1);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, sphost. Don't lose hope! Can you add a [mcve] of your code to the question using the snippet tool `[<>]` in the edit toolbar so we can see what you've done so far?

Comment: @Andy Hello, I added some parts of my code. Thank you for your reply

Comment: You have to wrap that SVG path in an SVG element - which you should size explicitly.

Comment: @MichaelMullany it is in SVG element

Comment: span is an HTML element, it's not a valid SVG element.

Comment: @RobertLongson do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: well the SVG text container elements are <text> and <tspan> but you'll struggle to create either with jQuery

Comment: @RobertLongson any idea how to do it with vanilla js?

Comment: you'd call document.createElementNS passing the SVG namespace as the first argument and 'text' as the second argument.

Comment: @sphost Also be aware that this topic is a frequently asked question on Stack Overflow. If you search SO, you will find plenty of potential solutions to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the system SVG tooltip `<title>` which pops up when you hover over a specific area

```html
<svg version="1.1"
       id="svg2"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="467 -284 959 593" xml:space="preserve">
<g>    
    <title>   "NV" - Nevada
      State capital city - Carson City
      Population
      City  55,274
      Estimate Estimate (2018)  55,414
      </title>
      <path fill="dodgerblue"  id="NV" class="state1" d="M663.4-98.4
        L639.8,30.4l-1.8,0.3l-1.6,2.4l-2.4,0l-1.5-2.7l-2.6-0.4l-0.8-1.1l-1-0.1l-2.8,1.6l-0.3,6.8l-0.4,5.8l-0.3,8.6l-1.4,2.1l-2.4-1.1
        L551.3-51.5l19-67.6L663.4-98.4z"/>
</g>    
</svg>
```

Below is an example of a map of several USA states

When you hover over a certain area of the map, it enlarges and a tooltip with text pops up

```js
document.querySelectorAll('path.state1').forEach(path => {
  path.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
    path.parentNode.parentNode.append(path.parentNode);
  });
});
```

```css
.state1 {
fill:white;
stroke:dodgerblue;
transform-origin: center center;
transform-box: fill-box;
transition:  1s;
}

:hover.state1 {
 fill:dodgerblue;
 stroke:white;
 stroke-width:2px;
 filter:url(#dropshadow);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
 transform: scale(1.5);
 
 }
```

```html
<body>
   <section id="map">

    <svg version="1.1"
       id="svg2" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="467 -284 959 593" xml:space="preserve">
      <defs>
    <filter id="dropshadow" height="130%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3"/> 
      <feOffset dx="2" dy="2" result="offsetblur"/> 
      <feMerge> 
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> 
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>
      <g>
      <title>"ID" - IDAHO
      State capital city - Boise
      Population - 228,790
      </title>
      <path id="ID"  class="state1" d="
        M615.5-107.5l8.8-35.2l1.4-4.2l2.5-5.9l-1.3-2.3l-2.5,0.1l-0.8-1l0.5-1.1l0.3-3.1l4.5-5.5l1.8-0.5l1.1-1.1l0.6-3.2l0.9-0.7l3.9-5.8
        l3.9-4.3l0.2-3.8l-3.4-2.6l-1.5-4.4l13.6-63.3l13.5,2.5l-4.4,21.4l3.6,7.5l-1.6,4.7l2,4.6l3.1,1.3l3.8,9.6l3.5,4.4l0.5,1.1l3.3,1.1
        l0.4,2.1l-7,17.4l-0.2,2.6l2.6,3.3l0.9,0l4.9-3l0.7-1.1l1.6,0.7l-0.3,5.4l2.7,12.6l3.9,3.2l1.7,2.2l-0.7,4.1l1.1,2.8l1.1,1.1
        l2.5-2.4l2.8,0l2.9,1.3l2.8-0.7l3.8-0.2l4,1.6l2.7-0.3l0.5-3l2.9-0.8l1.3,1.5l0.4,2.9l1.4,1.2l-8.4,53.6
        C710.4-89.3,622.5-106,615.5-107.5z"/> 
        </g>
  <g>    
    <title>   "UT" - Utah
      State capital city - Salt Lake City
      Population
      City  186,440
      Estimate Estimate (2018)  200,591
      </title>
      <path id="UT"  class="state1" d="M726.5,26.1l-83.7-11.9
        l20.6-112.5l46.8,8.7l-1.5,10.6l-2.3,13.2l7.8,0.9l16.4,1.8l8.2,0.9L726.5,26.1z"/>
</g>
      <g>    
    <title>   "AZ" - Arizona
      State capital city - Phoenix
      Population
      City  1,445,632
      Estimate Estimate (2018)  1,660,272
      </title>
      <path id="AZ" class="state1" d="
        M611.9,98.6l-2.6,2.2l-0.3,1.5l0.5,1l18.9,10.7l12.1,7.6l14.7,8.6l16.8,10l12.3,2.4l25,2.7l17.3-119.1l-83.7-11.9l-3.1,16.4l-1.6,0
        l-1.7,2.6l-2.5-0.1l-1.3-2.7l-2.7-0.3l-0.9-1.1H628l-0.9,0.6l-1.9,1l-0.1,7l-0.2,1.7l-0.6,12.6l-1.5,2.2l-0.6,3.3l2.7,4.9l1.3,5.8
        l0.8,1l1,0.6l-0.1,2.3l-1.6,1.4l-3.4,1.7l-1.9,1.9l-1.5,3.7l-0.6,4.9l-2.9,2.7l-2.1,0.7l0.1,0.8l-0.5,1.7l0.5,0.8l3.7,0.6l-0.6,2.7
        l-1.5,2.2L611.9,98.6z"/>
</g>        
<g>    
    <title>   "NV" - Nevada
      State capital city - Carson City
      Population
      City  55,274
      Estimate Estimate (2018)  55,414
      </title>
      <path id="NV" class="state1" d="M663.4-98.4
        L639.8,30.4l-1.8,0.3l-1.6,2.4l-2.4,0l-1.5-2.7l-2.6-0.4l-0.8-1.1l-1-0.1l-2.8,1.6l-0.3,6.8l-0.4,5.8l-0.3,8.6l-1.4,2.1l-2.4-1.1
        L551.3-51.5l19-67.6L663.4-98.4z"/>
</g>        
<g>    
    <title>   "OR" - Oregon
      State capital city - Salem
      Population
      City  154,637
      Estimate Estimate (2018)  173,442
      </title>
      <path id="OR" class="state1" d="
        M615.7-108.5l8.9-34.8l1.1-4.2l2.4-5.6l-0.6-1.2l-2.5,0l-1.3-1.7l0.5-1.5l0.5-3.2l4.5-5.5l1.8-1.1l1.1-1.1l1.5-3.6l4-5.7l3.6-3.9
        l0.2-3.5l-3.3-2.5l-1.8-4.6l-12.7-3.6l-15.1-3.5l-15.4,0.1l-0.5-1.4l-5.5,2.1l-4.5-0.6l-2.4-1.6l-1.3,0.7l-4.7-0.2l-1.7-1.4
        l-5.3-2.1l-0.8,0.1l-4.3-1.5l-1.9,1.8l-6.2-0.3l-5.9-4.1l0.7-0.8l0.2-7.8l-2.3-3.9l-4.1-0.6l-0.7-2.5l-2.4-0.5l-5.8,2.1l-2.3,6.5
        l-3.2,10l-3.2,6.5l-5,14.1l-6.5,13.6l-8.1,12.6l-1.9,2.9l-0.8,8.6l0.4,12.1L615.7-108.5z"/>
</g>     
     <g>
      <title>   "WA" - Washington Territory
      State capital city - Olympia
      Population
      City  46,478
      Estimate (2018)   52,555
      </title>
      <path id="WA" class="state1"  d="
        M569.1-276.4l4.4,1.5l9.7,2.7l8.6,1.9l20,5.7l23,5.7l15.2,3.2l-13.6,63.6l-12.4-3.5l-15.5-3.6l-15.2,0l-0.5-1.3l-5.6,2.2l-4.6-0.7
        l-2.1-1.6L579-200l-4.7-0.1l-1.7-1.3l-5.3-2.1l-0.7,0.1l-4.4-1.5l-1.9,1.8l-6.3-0.3l-5.9-4.1l0.8-0.9l0.1-7.7l-2.3-3.8l-4.1-0.6
        l-0.7-2.5l-2.3-0.5l-3.6,1.2l-2.3-3.2l0.3-2.9l2.7-0.3l1.6-4l-2.6-1.1l0.2-3.7l4.4-0.6l-2.7-2.7l-1.5-7.1l0.6-2.9v-7.9l-1.8-3.2
        l2.3-9.4l2.1,0.5l2.4,2.9l2.7,2.6l3.2,1.9l4.5,2.1l3.1,0.6l2.9,1.5l3.4,1l2.3-0.2v-2.4l1.3-1.1l2.1-1.3l0.3,1.1l0.3,1.8l-2.3,0.5
        l-0.3,2.1l1.8,1.5l1.1,2.4l0.6,1.9l1.5-0.2l0.2-1.3l-1-1.3l-0.5-3.2l0.8-1.8l-0.6-1.5v-2.3l1.8-3.6l-1.1-2.6l-2.4-4.9l0.3-0.8
        L569.1-276.4z M559.6-270.4l2-0.2l0.5,1.4l1.5-1.6h2.3l0.8,1.5l-1.5,1.7l0.6,0.8l-0.7,2l-1.4,0.4c0,0-0.9,0.1-0.9-0.2
        s1.5-2.6,1.5-2.6l-1.7-0.6l-0.3,1.5l-0.7,0.6l-1.5-2.3L559.6-270.4z"/>
  </g> 
  <g>
      <title>   "CA" - California
      State capital city - Sacramento
      Population
      City  466,488
      Estimate (2018)   508,529
      </title>
      <path id="CA" class="state1" d="
        M611.7,98.2l3.9-0.5l1.5-2l0.5-2.9l-3.6-0.6l-0.5-0.7l0.5-2l-0.2-0.6l1.9-0.6l3-2.8l0.6-5l1.4-3.4l1.9-2.2l3.5-1.6l1.7-1.6l0.1-2.1
        l-1-0.6l-1-1.1l-1.2-5.8l-2.7-4.8l0.6-3.5l-2.4-1L551.3-51.5l18.9-67.6l-67.1-15.7l-1.5,4.7l-0.2,7.4l-5.2,11.8l-3.1,2.6l-0.3,1.1
        l-1.8,0.8l-1.5,4.2l-0.8,3.2l2.7,4.2l1.6,4.2l1.1,3.6l-0.3,6.5l-1.8,3.1l-0.6,5.8l-1,3.7l1.8,3.9l2.7,4.5l2.3,4.9l1.3,4l-0.3,3.2
        l-0.3,0.5v2.1l5.7,6.3l-0.5,2.4l-0.6,2.3l-0.6,1.9l0.2,8.2l2.1,3.7l1.9,2.6l2.7,0.5l1,2.7l-1.1,3.6l-2.1,1.6h-1.1l-0.8,3.9l0.5,2.9
        l3.2,4.4l1.6,5.3l1.5,4.7l1.3,3.1l3.4,5.8l1.5,2.6l0.5,2.9l1.6,1v2.4l-0.8,1.9l-1.8,7.1l-0.5,1.9l2.4,2.7l4.2,0.5l4.5,1.8l3.9,2.1
        h2.9l2.9,3.1l2.6,4.9l1.1,2.3l3.9,2.1l4.8,0.8l1.5,2.1l0.6,3.2l-1.5,0.6l0.3,1l3.2,0.8l2.7,0.2l3.2-1.7l3.9,4.2l0.8,2.3l2.6,4.2
        l0.3,3.2v9.4l0.5,1.8l10,1.5l19.7,2.7L611.7,98.2z M523.6,54.5l1.3,1.5l-0.2,1.3l-3.2-0.1l-0.6-1.2l-0.6-1.5L523.6,54.5z
         M525.5,54.5l1.2-0.6l3.6,2.1l3.1,1.2l-0.9,0.6l-4.5-0.2l-1.6-1.6L525.5,54.5z M546.2,74.3l1.8,2.3l0.8,1l1.5,0.6l0.6-1.5l-1-1.8
        l-2.7-2l-1.1,0.2V74.3z M544.7,82.9l1.8,3.2l1.2,1.9l-1.5,0.2l-1.3-1.2c0,0-0.7-1.5-0.7-1.9s0-2.2,0-2.2L544.7,82.9z"/>
        </g>
    </svg>

  </section>
</body>
```